# How to hide scrollbar in electron's BrowserView?

Tags: iframe, electron, web-content

I am trying electron's [BrowserView](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view) to embed third party web content in an Electron BrowserWindow.

My electron version is `10`.

```
// In the main process.
const { BrowserView, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

const view = new BrowserView()
win.setBrowserView(view)
view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300 })
view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org')
```

This is working fine and now I wanted to hide `scrollbars` by adding a line

```
view.webContents.insertCSS('html, body { overflow: hidden; }')
```

but this is not hiding scrollbar.
How can I hide `scrollbar` in `BrowserView`?

Comment: what do you mean "but this is hiding scrollbar". You mean it's not? Your code works for me in Electron 12. What Electron version are you on?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I have edited question. I am using electron 10

Comment: could you try Electron 12 to see if that fixes it?

Comment: Thank you, yes upgrading to electron 12 is fixing this problem.